# Numpy / Pandas efficient matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very large matrix which will have X many rows and either 10,000 or 1 columns per row. Something like:

```
[[0, 1, 2, ..., 9999],
 [10000, 10001, ..., 19999],
 [20000],
 [20001, 20002, ..., 30000]]
```

I want to be able to sum down the columns e.g. `[50001, 50004, ..., 79998]` but I don't think I can create a `numpy.array` or a `pandas.DataFrame` to accommodate this without repeating the `20000` value 10,000 times.

I've currently hacked a solution into `pandas`, but I was hoping there's a better way.

My `pandas` "solution" is to use a single column with python `list`s in them or a single value (I can't seem to use a `numpy.array` or `pandas` will assume I'm trying to set those values across multiple indices). Here's what the above looks like with my jank solution:

```
DataFrame
             value
0:    [0, 1, 2, ..., 9999]
1: [10000, 10001, ..., 19999]
2:           20000
3: [20001, 20002, ..., 30000]
```

---

```
df['value'].agg(lambda vs: np.array(vs.apply(np.array).sum()).tolist())
```

That's pretty ugly, but allows for the memory efficiency of a single value for index 2.

Is there a cleaner less error prone way of using `numpy` or `pandas` to do this? Or a way of doing this which won't bust the memory on my machine if opting to repeat single values.

Thanks

Comment: look for from csc_matrix from scipy.sparse

Comment: @RaoSahab This looks promising by name though I'm struggling to find much documentation describing how it works - other then boilerplate API description. But will keep looking